# How to edit Python Add-In and get all changes to work?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-addin

I have created an Add-In using Python. However, when I edit the Python script for that Add-In and re-create the '.esriaddin' file, I don't get updated results when using that Add-In. Do I need to re-create the Add-In each time when I edit my Python script to cater to changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps for editing existing Python add-ins are described **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Editing_add_ins/014p0000001v000000/)**.

One of those steps is to **[Test your add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Testing_an_add_in/014p00000026000000/)** and the first step of that is to "Make the add-in file" by running the makeaddin.py script.

Consequently, I would expect that you do need to re-create the Add-in.

It is certainly worth giving that a try.

Comment: Thanks. I learned from ESRI python forum that I have to restart ArcMap each time when I re-create Add-In using python.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I found the other way to do it:

Adding to your script I just import module (but with fixed path) and do all your scripting in module. So it should look like that:

```
 def onClick(self):
    import imp
    print "start"
    mytestmodule = "mytestmodule.py"
    mymod = imp.load_source("mytestmodule", mypath+os.sep+mytestmodule)
    mymod.GetFrameName()
```

Now you can call any methods from module. Not sure yet if I can create a class there with onClick event?